# Moderators Pro Tempore IN SPAAAAACE!

Tags: discussion, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Monica Cellio]
[image: Michael Kjörling]
[image: Tim B]
[image: Vincent]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Congrats everyone!

Comment: Thanks @DonyorM :)

Comment: You've chosen the best people for the job IMHO!

Comment: Thanks everybody!

Comment: Let us know how we can help.  Congrats.

Comment: @James, the best ways to help are to keep doing what everybody's been doing so well already -- share great questions and answers, offer a helping hand to people learning the ropes, edit or comment to improve what you find, check the review queues, and engage on meta.  Choose whatever subset of that works for you. :-)

Comment: Congrats to the new moderators! The first 10 days have been good so far.

Comment: @NormalHuman Actually in spite of expectations, [theirs was quite terrestrial](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/questions/298/moderator-pro-tem-announcement).

Comment: @GraceNote All that's missing is their site being launched.

Comment: A new Moderator? Whoot, congrats @Vincent

Answer (score 15):

I'd like to thank all four of our pro-tem mods for their service to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange.

We just finished [our first election](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election/1), and, sadly, Vincent and Michael Kjörling will be leaving us as mods.

Michael Kjörling, thanks for helping to guide us through the early stages of the site, especially on meta. You've helped us get through a lot of tricky discussions on scope, tagging, design, and a host of other topics, as well as providing a lot of great questions and answers on the main site.

Vincent, you stepped up when the site needed you most, and spent so much time tagging, retagging, editing, and organizing tag wikis - both with meta posts and behind-the-scenes edits. I don't know if people appreciated those contributions enough; they've proved important in improving hundreds and hundreds of questions.

I hope the both of you will stay around and keep on doing what you do best: Guiding the site through tough times in a variety of ways. Thank you so much for all you've done for Worldbuilding Stack Exchange.

Monica Cellio and Tim B, you guys have also done fantastic stuff during the beta phase, and I'm glad that you'll be staying on as mods.

Monica, you've done so much to bring Worldbuilding to an important place in the network. You helped promote us through the blog and made use of your many connections on other sites to get our name out there, and improve inter-site relations.

Tim B, you've also done many of the same things Monica did. Your blog posts have been awesome. You've also gotten us onto the HNQ list through many good, popular questions. I look forward to seeing more in the future.

All four of you guys were the most important force in helping Worldbuilding graduate in a relatively short time (only a year or so!). I look forward to your continued guidance in a number of ways in the time to come.

Comment: Awwwwww, /tear.  (but seriously thanks everyone)

Comment: Thanks for the kind words HDE. Welcome to the team.

Comment: @James hey Michael came back! I hope this makes you a bit happier, as you're now going to serve alongside him :)